# Dropbox access token api call raised error using JavaScript and Axios

Tags: cors, dropbox-api

Currently I'm working on Dropbox integration within my VueJS project and I'm able to get authorization code successfully. But unfortunately unable to get call access token API using JS and Axios. Whenever call the API it raise following error:

[image]

And my calling API endpoints:

```
let url = "https://dropbox.com/oauth2/token?client_id="+state.clientId+"&client_secret="+state.client_secret+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&code="+state.dropbox_code+"&scope="+scope+"&grant_type=authorization_code";      

await axios.post(url)`
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to programmatically make an `XMLHttpRequest` to 'dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize', however that's actually a web page, and not something that should be called programmatically. You should be directing the end-user to that page in their browser. Refer to the Dropbox [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the api endpoint is "oauth2/token" not the "oauth2/authorize". So, for both is yours answer would be same?

Comment: Unlike /oauth2/authorize, the /oauth2/token endpoint is meant to be accessed programmatically. The /oauth2/token endpoint is used by the app after the user authorizes the app via /oauth2/authorize.

Answer (score -1):

Yeh, finally I solved the issue myself by using "fetch" method instead of "axios".

Solution sample: `let url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token?client_id="+state.clientId+"&client_secret="+state.client_secret+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&code="+state.dropbox_code+"&grant_type=authorization_code";

```
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',       
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',       
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => state.dropbox_access_response = data )
  .catch(err => console.log('access err =>',err));`
```